# Using more than one argument in where clause JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm using this code below and its working well. In this case, I'm using only one clause in where like you can see:

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public ObjectTest serach(String x) {
            return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT TOP 1 field1\n" +
            "  ,field2\n" +
            "  ,field3\n" +
            "  FROM [BD].[TEST].[TABLE]\n" +
            "  where field1 = ?", new Object[]{x},               
    (rs, rowNum) -> new ObjectTest (
            rs.getInt("field1"),
            rs.getString("field2"),
            rs.getString("field3")
    ));
}
```

In this case, searching some documentation and examples, i've figured out that I only need to write 
**" where field1 = ?", new Object[]{x},** when I have one argument in the where clause, but now I would like to have more than one (like x and y values), I mean, using the **AND** statement, and I'm not finding the correct syntax to do it.

Comment: Which has nothing *at all* to do with the JPA API.

Comment: Sorry I'll remove the tags, I didn't know. Thanks for the advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to do:

```
    ...
public ObjectTest serach(String x. String y) {
            return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT TOP 1 field1\n" +
            "  ,field2\n" +
            "  ,field3\n" +
            "  FROM [BD].[TEST].[TABLE]\n" +
            "  where field1 = ?\n" + 
            " and field2 = ?", new Object[]{x, y},
    ...
```

And it will populate the `?` ordinally based on your input array.

However, I would take a look at the [`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) ([see the example in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#jdbc-NamedParameterJdbcTemplate)). It's cleaner because you'll be able to write your query with the `?` arguments as names, i.e. `:field1`.